# JPA @ManyToOne unidirectional mapping with key = id + tenant_id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I'm programming a Multi-Tenant application. The tenant_id is present in every table and is part of each PK.
My tables are:

```
table S {
  tenant_id PK
  id        PK
  pid
  ...
}

table P {
  tenant_id PK
  id       PK
  ...
}
```

Table S has a PK made up with (tenant_id, id). Table P has a PK made up with (tenant_id, id).  Table S links to table P via (S.tenant_id = P.tenant_id and S.pid = P.id)

**When I've implemented this in Java JPA, I can read table S including P, but adding a S has a strange behavior: JPA adds the missing P but doesn't fill S.pid so the P is correct but there is no link from S to P.**

I don't want to have bidirectional links because P is also referred to by other fields of other tables.

My problem is somewhat similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70493925/jpa-unidirectionnal-manytomany-with-multiple-field-primary-keys-multi-tenant-ap) which has no answer yet.

The Java classes look like (simplified):

```
@Embeddable
public class MultiTenantId implements Serializable {
    
    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private String tenantId;
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "P")
public class P {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MultiTenantId id;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "S")
public class S {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MultiTenantId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id", referencedColumnName = "tenant_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "pid", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)}
    )
    private P p;
    ...
}
```

- If I don't set the `insertable = false, updatable = false` then error
  because the tenant_id is already used (in the MultiTenantId and in
  this @ManyToOne)
- if I set them then reading is OK but adding a S via JPA has a strange effect in the DB: it correctly adds the P, correctly adds the S except that it never sets the pid in the table S ==> the link is not done.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help, I'm completely lost with this problem !!

Comment: Did you try just setting `insertable = false, updatable = false` for `tenant_id`? If you're not allowing the relation to update `pid` it's not surprising this doesn't happen.

Comment: for `tenant_id` you mean in the @JoinColumns annotation ?
I tried but JPA refuses to put this annotation on just one of the @JoinColumn. It must be on every or none.